# Get a webuserControl's value automatically created

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have  added a WebUserControl dynamically ,and then i wanted to get it, here is my story :(  i don't know how to do it , here is my code,
thanks in advance,

```
 Protected Sub btngenerate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btngenerate.Click

    For Each Str As String In Tstring
        Dim addressControl As WebUC = CType(LoadControl("WebUC.ascx"), WebUC)

        addressControl.plbl.Text = Str
        form1.Controls.Add(addressControl)
    Next


End Sub



Protected Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click


 'here is what i did , but it didn't work
 'For Each ct As WebUCIn form1.Controls
 ' ltlres.Text = ltlres.Text & ", " & ct.plbl.Text & " " & ct.ptxt.Text

 'Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule to adding controls dynamically. You had to add them back on `Init` for as long as you need them.

Just adding them on a button click will show them the first time, but you will not receive any inputs from them.

You can keep a flag in the session to denote that they have to be added on `Init`

Comment: So  form1.Controls.Add(addressControl) will be on Init and what i have to do on click event ?

Comment: You add it on the click event the first time. But from then on, you add it again in Init whenever a postback occurs after that

Answer (score 0):

Because you added that control dynamically, when you post back, you'll need to add it again in order for its ViewState and postback data to be associated with it.

Re-create it in the `Init` event, and then when you process control events (like button clicks) it will exist and will have its data (such as the contents of its child controls) associated with it.

Since you're creating the control as a response to another event, you'll need to keep some kind of flag (a boolean?  A counter?) in Session in order to know whether or not to re-create it on `Init`.

Comment: Ok , does this mean that the click event will simply show the controls ?

Comment: `btngenerate_Click` will create and add the control, and you'll put some kind of flag or counter in Session.  Then, when you post back, you'll read the flag/counter and re-create the control in `Init`.  Then when `btnOK_Click` is executed, the control will be there for you to access.